# What is the purpose of a "Hell bringer"?

Tags: diablo-iii

This may seem like a dumb question, but I have seen in Act III objects that my (AI) mercinary will attack called `Hell Bringer`.  I assume they summon some sort of enemy or enemies [by its title], but I have been practically touching one before and **nothing spawned near me.**

What is their purpose and why does my friend want to attack them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They normally spawn Tormented Stingers, which can be seen in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyA2gZQRFfk) Youtube video. It is possible that they had already spawned and you never noticed. I am not sure if the Hell Bringer can spawn multiple times given a cooldown. I always kill them before they have a chance. Clearly your follower has the same idea.

Comment: Ah in the midst of battle, I must not have noticed.  Thank you!